# Kivy- How to receive data from a server continuously and update the interface using kivy

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, twisted, kivy

I'm developing a GUI with kivy.

What I would like to do is receive data from a server and update continuously the interface with the data received. How can I achieve this? Looking around the web I red about Twisted reactor, multithreading, kivy clock base object, non-blocking operation, but I'm a bit lost, I don't know what could suit my needs.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this out http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html

Comment: I imagine what you use might depend on the type and volume of the data you are planning to receive. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Well I have to receive a Json packet (of 6 int and 4 string) every second to update the interface, I looked at the link you posted and it seems to me a bit difficult to understand so i'm currently trying with socket python module and select function to set timeout, but I'm quite stalled because I don't know yet how to schedule the setting of the connection and the retrieving of the data in the kivy event loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted would be my recommendation. It has good performance and is already integrated into the Kivy event loop. We use Twisted for all network communication in our enterprise Kivy application.

The [link provided by Totem in the comments](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html) is a good simple example of using Twisted with Kivy. If you control both ends of the communication then I would recommend looking at Twisted's [Perspective Broker](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/core/howto/pb-usage.html).

Comment: Ok I'll try with Twisted, it's too much if ask you some snippet of your network communication code? Thank you for your answer.